# AngularJS : Access radio button value change in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a few radio buttons with certain value. What I'm trying to achieve is, on selecting certain radio buttons, it's value should add up and be displayed as total.

Here is my AngularJS directive and controller code :

```
angular.module('mapp',[])

.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){


    $scope.items = [
        {'Id':1, 'Cost':100},
        {'Id':2,'Cost':200}
        ];

    $scope.total = 0;
}])

.directive('customElement',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            data: '=info'
        },
        template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="data">\
                    <span>{{data}}</span>'
    }
});
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<div ng-app="mapp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">

        <custom-element ng-repeat="item in items" info="item.Cost"></custom-element>

        <br/>
        <br/> Total: <span>{{total}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8kpddb92/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by passing in two different arguments to the directive: `data` (for the label) and then a secondary boolean `selected` to determine whether the item is selected or not.

**Javascript:**

```
angular.module('mapp',[])

.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){


    $scope.items = [
        {'Id':1, 'Cost':100, selected: false},
        {'Id':2,'Cost':200, selected: false}
    ];

    $scope.total = function () {

        var selectedItems = $scope.items.filter(function (d) { return d.selected; });
        console.log('items = ', $scope.items);
        var totalSum = 0;
        selectedItems.forEach(function (item) {
            totalSum += item['Cost'];
        });
        return totalSum;
    };
}])

.directive('customElement',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            data: '=info',
            selected: '=selected'
        },
        template: '<input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="true">\
                    <span>{{data}}</span>'
    }
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<custom-element ng-repeat="item in items" 
                info="item.Cost" 
                selected="item.selected">
</custom-element>
```

Finally, you'll need to calculate the `total` via a getter.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vv46xs0c/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't succeeded with radio buttons (I don't know much about this thing :-(, and I could not "uncheck" the radio buttons ), but I've succeeded with checkboxes

Here is your updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8kpddb92/4/

What did I have to change :

`ng-model` needed a boolean

adding a function inside your controller

```
$scope.handleChange = function(){
    $scope.total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.items.length; i++){
        if ($scope.items[i].isSelected)
            $scope.total += $scope.items[i].Cost;
    }
}
```

And calling this function inside the child directive :

```
    template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.isSelected" ng-change=$parent.handleChange()>\
                <span>{{data.Cost}}</span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to make a new scope. Just use the 'item' from the repeat. Call a change function on click, pass the item, and you are good to go :)

```
angular.module('mapp',[])

.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){


        $scope.items = [
            {'Id':1, 'Cost':100},
            {'Id':2,'Cost':200}
        ];

        $scope.total = 0;

        $scope.change = function(item) {
            $scope.total = item.Cost;
        };

    }])

    .directive('customElement',function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<input type="radio" name="radios" ng-click="change(item)"><span>{{item.Cost}}</span>'
        }
    });
```

Comment: a demo would be appreciated :)

Comment: there are only a few lines changed compared to your code :) pretty sure you will figure it out